# spark cannot access customer's s3 bucket from emr

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I am struggling to connect to another account's s3 bucket. The problem is I can connect to the bucket via s3 API

```
def listFilesAndRename(key : String) = {
    val clientBucket = "test"
    val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access key", "secret key")
    val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard.withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build

  val result = s3.listObjectsV2(clientBucket, key)
  val objects = result.getObjectSummaries.toArray
  for {
    os <- objects
    fileName = os.asInstanceOf[S3ObjectSummary].getKey
    if !fileName.endsWith("_SUCCESS")
       } {
    System.out.println("* " + os.asInstanceOf[S3ObjectSummary].getKey)
  }
}
```

but when i want to connect using spark, it does not work. I tried the following settings

```
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "access key")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "secret key")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
```

Caused by:

```
com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 799F611A3D7BB5E1; S3 Extended Request ID: USTzJmBtWt27ccvF+YuTogwDSknuvB2tBLHxqPySLwftHXfmPpPYVjqVubzeVnqjJS89fzIjJw8=)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
```

So clearly this is not a connection error, but looks like spark is unable to connect to the s3 bucket

Comment: `EMR` and `s3-bucket` are on the same aws account?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the bucket's permissions. according to the error, you're not allowed to access the data

Comment: @Cesar - yes they are run via spark sql in the same cluster via the same account.

Comment: @Mahmoud - I would like to think so, but the Analysts are able to write to the bucket and read via other means. Just Spark I not able to do it.

Comment: Maybe something related IAM user that you are using on the EMR. The role should have s3 access for read and write.

Comment: @CesarA.Mostacero - Is the user that spark-shell uses different from the emr role? Can you please tell me how I can find the user-id from soark-shell?

Comment: You can get that information from aws.console. Check the user that is attached to that emr and then check if it has s3 access (w/r).